# Не могу настроить изменение `transform.rotation` персонажа с помощью виртуального джойстика

Tags: c#, unity3d

Не могу настроить адекватное изменение `transform.rotation` персонажа с помощью виртуального джойстика.
Налево и направо персонаж поворачивается вроде нормально - на скриншоте я отобразил зелеными стрелками.
Вверх,вниз и по диагонали персонаж поворачивается неправильно - на скриншоте я отобразил красными стрелками
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Видео как это все на данный момент работает - https://youtu.be/2NWMwxXn2mc
**Пояснение для видео:**

- с 1 по 6 секунды я показываю как персонаж правильно поворачивается по
  горизонтали (вправо-влево)
- с 6 по 24 секунды я показываю неправильное    поворачивание персонажа
  по диагонали и вверх-вниз.

**Как должно работать:** тяну джойстик вверх - персонаж поворачивается вверх, тяну джойстик вниз - персонаж поворачивается вниз, тоже самое для всех сторон, включая повороты по диагонали
В математике к сожалению я мягко говоря не силен
Скрипт:

```
public Joystick joystick;
float tiltAngle = 180.0f;
float smooth = 5.0f;

void Update ()
{
    Quaternion target = Quaternion.Euler(0, joystick.Vertical * tiltAngle, 0);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, target,  Time.deltaTime * smooth);

    Quaternion target2 = Quaternion.Euler(0, joystick.Horizontal * tiltAngle, 0);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, target2,  Time.deltaTime * smooth);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решил проблему и также добавил передвижение с помощью Velocity!**

```
    if (joystick.Vertical != 0 && joystick.Horizontal != 0)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(joystick.Horizontal, 0f, joystick.Vertical)),
            speed * Time.deltaTime);

        rb.velocity = new Vector3(joystick.Horizontal * movementSpeed, rb.velocity.y,
            joystick.Vertical * movementSpeed);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. для начала нужно определится управление идет от персонажа или от камеры. Этого не написано. То есть абсолютные повороты или же относительные.
2. Предположу что персонаж должен реагировать относительно камеры.
3. Нужно просчитывать теперешнее направление камеры.
4. Нужно провести манипуляции для перевода абсолютных углов поворота (система координат мира) в углы поворота персонажа (система координат относительно камеры). Скорее всего это решается добавлением или вычетанием векторов включая только пару значений вектора. Хз какие -- разберись сам.
5. А потом уже привязывать джостик к повороту персонажа. То есть приводить систему координат экрана (x,y) -- позицию джостика в систему координат относительно камеры. Поворачиваешь джостик налево -- поворачивает налево и бежит. Поворачиваешь направо -- идентично.

А тот код который у тебя сейчас перестанет работать как только ты сменишь направление камеры, скорее всего)

И вот еще может быть полезным: [Как сделать управление, как в игре "Overcooked"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/931703/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b5-overcooked)