# Как сделать управление, как в игре "Overcooked"?

Tags: unity3d

Хочу сделать управление игроком, как в игре "Overcooked".

[Трейлер](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ZK7veYPEJQ) с геймплеем.

Моё текущее управление игроком.

[image]

**PlayerController.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControllerTransform : MonoBehaviour {

    private string moveInputAxis = "Vertical";
    private string turnInputAxis = "Horizontal";

    public float rotationRate = 360f;
    public float moveSpeed = 1;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        float moveAxis = Input.GetAxis (moveInputAxis);
        float turnAxis = Input.GetAxis (turnInputAxis);

        //Обновляет каждый кадр наше положение и поворот
        ApplyInput (moveAxis, turnAxis);
    }

    private void ApplyInput(float moveInput, float turnInput)
    {
        Move (moveInput);
        Turn(turnInput);
    }

    private void Move(float input)
    {
        transform.Translate (Vector3.forward*input*moveSpeed);//Можно добавить Time.DeltaTime
    }

    private void Turn(float input)
    {
        transform.Rotate (0,input * rotationRate * Time.deltaTime,0);
    }
}
```

В чём проблема. В игре куда нажал (WASD), туда носом повернул и пошёл.(Как я понял) У меня же на данный момент, управление больше похоже на управление машиной. A-D-отвечают за поворот. W-вперёд,S-назад.

В итоге хочу сделать управление аналогичное игровому.

p.s. Ещё [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KmTTlHrm9pY) с геймплеем, чтобы понять лучше игровое управление.

Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Вообще с вопросами "Как игра X сделала Y" лучше обращаться к самим разработчикам. И не потому что кому "лень" отвечать на такие вопросы, а просто потому что зачастую довольно сложно воссоздать что-то из другой игры 1в1.

---

Наверняка такое можно сделать и другим способом, но я решил пойти через 2 этапа:

1. вращение персонажа в зависимости от ввода
2. перемещение персонажа через `transform.forward`, благо персонаж в данной игре всегда двигается только лицом вперед

---

**Ввод данных**

Тут все максимально просто и не отличается от варианта в вопросе, но записываю я все это дело в вектор, чтобы потом получать через него углы и прочие нужные вещи:

```
private Vector3 moveVector;

...

void HandleInput() {
    moveVector.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    moveVector.z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
}
```

---

**Вращение**

Казалось бы, можно просто использовать

```
transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, Vector3.Angle(transform.forward, moveVector));
```

Но `Vector3.Angle` возвращает **наименьший** угол между векторами, т.е. от 0 до 180, что приводит к таким результатам при вращении на угол от 0 до 360:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Один из выходов из данной ситуации - написать свою функцию определения угла между векторами для диапазона углов [0..360]:

```
float Angle360(Vector3 from, Vector3 to, Vector3 right) {
    float angle = Vector3.Angle(from, to);
    return (Vector3.Angle(right, to) > 90f) ? 360f - angle : angle;
}
```

Такую функцию очень просто найти в гугле - не хочу перегружать вопрос ее объяснением.

А затем применяем все это дело в `Update`:

```
void Update () {
    HandleInput();

    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, Angle360(transform.forward, moveVector, transform.right));
}
```

И получаем почти нужное нам вращение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Перемещение**

Все практически элементарно: использует `Transform.Translate`, не забывая добавить переменную для скорости:

```
public float speed = 2f;

...

transform.Translate(transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
```

Данный код будет постоянно двигать объект по направлению его локального "прямо". Но мы хотим двигать его только при вводе пользователя.

Логичный выход из ситуации - использовать модуль вектора `moveVector`, предварительно его нормализовав, дабы получить значение в диапазоне [0..1]:

```
transform.Translate(
    moveVector.normalized.sqrMagnitude * transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime,
    Space.World
);
```

В данном случае можно использовать квадрат модуля просто потому что квадрат модуля всегда будет равен либо `0`, либо `1`, а `sqrt(1) == 1/-1`, `sqrt(0) == 0`. `-1` нас по понятным причинам не беспокоит.

Но чисто по ощущениям - результаты я не замерял, проще обойтись вообще без этого модуля и сделать вот так:

```
float Moves() {
    if(moveVector.x != 0 || moveVector.z != 0) {
        return 1f;
    }
    else {
        return 0f;
    }
}
```

Стоит отметить, что данный метод будет всегда выдавать вектор движения 1. Если игра поддерживает геймпады, где джойстики могут выдавать значения по обеим осям [0..1], лучше использовать модуль вектора.

И подставив результат этого метода в `Translate`.

---

В конечном итоге получили какой-то такой компонент:

```
public class OvercookedLikeMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 2f;

    private Vector3 moveVector;

    void Update () {
        HandleInput();

        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, Angle360(transform.forward, moveVector, transform.right));

        transform.Translate(
            Moves() * transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime,
            Space.World
        );
    }

    void HandleInput() {
        moveVector.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        moveVector.z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    }

    float Moves() {
        if(moveVector.x != 0 || moveVector.z != 0)
            return 1f;
        else
            return 0f;
    }

    float Angle360(Vector3 from, Vector3 to, Vector3 right) {
        float angle = Vector3.Angle(from, to);
        return (Vector3.Angle(right, to) > 90f) ? 360f - angle : angle;
    }
}
```

Результат в Unity:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

### P.S.

Видно, что объект иногда двигается рывками. Причиной этому служит резкая смена угла поворота объекта, это не баг, а закономерный результат кода выше и чище без интерполяции не сделать.

Что бы я сделал на вашем месте?

Посмотрел бы в сторону Tween движков для Unity, с помощью которых можно все это дело сгладить и сделать более натуральным, что ли. Но результат на данный момент, как по мне, очень похож на OverCooked.

Comment: Вау! Я так восхищён вашим ответом. К сожалению, я уже сплю на ходу, но я обязательно прочту всё с утра. p.s. Гифки с результатом, круть.

Comment: Класный ответ, мое уважение, сэр)

Comment: @ArtikSlayer рад был помочь :)