# Unity3D: Движение персонажа от 3го лица с видом сверху

Tags: c#, unity3d

Суть проблемы: на сцене есть персонаж, главный герой, его необходимо двигать наэкранным джойстиком. Я написал простой скрипт, который двигает персонажа, но не могу разобраться как сделать так, чтобы персонаж поворачивался в ту же сторону, в которую двигается?

p.s я в юнити недавно, как и в с#, поэтому прошу ответить максимально подробно. Спасибо!

Comment: Указани поворота в градусах `transform.eulerAngles`. Всё остальное обычная математика.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/931703/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b5-overcooked/931793#931793