# Движение персонажа в Unity3d Android

Tags: android, unity3d

Доброе утро\вечер\день, господа и дамы.
Хочу сделать данное управление в игре, вперёд, влево, вправо, всё по стандарту. Возникает вопрос со следующей кнопкой, как сделать так, чтобы при повороте игрока, векторы были локальные и не сбивалось управление?
Т.е при старте игры всё хорошо, работает вперёд, влево, вправо, но при повороте на 90 градусов, скорее всего уже сами понимаете результат, вперёд это влево (или вправо, не помню уже), вправо это вперед и т.п.

На данной задачей сижу уже долго.
Движение игрока реализовано через rigidbody2d.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в Standart assets есть FirstPersonCharacter, оттуда  посмотри как реализован

Comment: проблема в том что за поворотом не поворачивается вектор направления движения?

Comment: Можно увидеть код управления?

Answer (score 0):

1. Нужно просчитывать теперешнее направление камеры.
2. Нужно провести манипуляции для перевода абсолютных углов поворота (система координат мира) в углы поворота персонажа (система координат относительно камеры). Скорее всего это решается добавлением или вычетанием векторов включая только пару значений вектора. Хз какие -- разберись сам.
3. А потом уже привязывать джостик к повороту персонажа. То есть приводить систему координат экрана (x,y) -- позицию джостика в систему координат относительно камеры. Поворачиваешь джостик налево -- поворачивает налево и бежит. Поворачиваешь направо -- идентично.

текст скопировал из своего ответа: [Не могу настроить изменение `transform.rotation` персонажа с помощью виртуального джойстика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/931571/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-transform-rotation-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3/931801#931801)